# Delay Div OnLoad

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a div that I would like to delay onLoad for a set period of time using jQuery.  Here is the code I have that isn't working:

```
$('#PriceBox').delay(8000).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: Exactly what "isn't working" ?

Comment: Any problem with your HTML code? Please set up a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V2Zwz/ -- Seems to work on its own, check your JS console to see if there are any errors stopping the execution of your code.

Comment: Are you sure its hidden in the first place i.e. css display:none?

Answer (score 11):

CSS:

```css
/** make sure the element is initially hidden */
​#PriceBox {
    display: none;   
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#PriceBox').delay(8000).fadeIn(400);
});
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/SQhv4/)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you need to start off your `div` as `display: none` and then put the display code in a `$(document).ready(..)`

```
<div id="PriceBox" style="display: none">Delay load me</div>​
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#PriceBox').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);  
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6B6he/