# Lazy loading parts of a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

I have a WordPress website that has a form which is integrated with a CRM. And it is causing the page to load slowly even with a caching plugin (W3 Total Cache) enabled.

I was wondering whether it is possible to load a particular div after the website has been loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay Div OnLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672580/delay-div-onload)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with the help of CSS and javascript/jQuery.

Set Display property of that div as none until it hasn't rendered completely in the DOM as:

```
#divName {
   display: none 
}
```

Now, the functionality to display on complete load can be written as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divName').delay(ms);
});
```

Note: Here, ms is count in milliseconds(1000, 2000, etc.)

I hope this will help. Cheers!

Comment: In this case, the content would still load but be hidden, right? I need a solution when content is loaded after the website has been loaded.

Comment: This means that while your page is fetching data, it won't display a bad UI. It is actually a very general approach to show loaders at this time. You might have been knowing this fact.